# Creating an editable slideshow (ideally a powerpoint) from R

Tags: r, powerpoint, r-markdown

As part of a contract, the team I work in has to produce a monthly powerpoint filled with KPI's and other requested values, which is then passed on to another team who write a commentary on last months performance. At the moment the values are created (mostly in SAS) exported to an excel file and then copy and pasted into a powerpoint. This is an old approach which clearly needs updating.

What I would ideally like to do is to automate the presentation using RMarkdown and save myself the hassle of copy and pasting values. The issue is that RMarkdown from what I can see can't produce a .ppt file, or another editable format that the commentary team could add to without having to use R.

From googling around the topic I found packages such as `rcom`, `RDCOMclient`, and `R2PPT` but they don't appear to have been recently updated or maintained.

TLDR; Need a way of making a powerpoint/slideshow in R where the text can be edited afterwards outside of R.

Comment: the `officer` package is awesome and will do what you want. I've used it to automate a client-targeted "report" that saved substantial hours of SME time.

Comment: You can easily edit RMarkdown.  It's not a WYSIWYG interface though...

Comment: Perhaps an ignorant question, but is there some reason why the update from Excel to PowerPoint *must* be done in R rather than from, say, VBA in the Excel workbook or in a template PPT presentation?

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with RStudio and pandoc 2.1:

1) install Pandoc 2 from pandoc.org (this is higher version than the one which currently comes with rstudio )

2) create your RMarkdown file in RStudio,

```
---
title: 'Some title'
author: 'author'
output:
  md_document: default
---
```

3) knit to md

4) call pandoc to convert to pptx

```
system("cmd", input = "C:\\Users\\janvy\\AppData\\Local\\Pandoc\\pandoc -f markdown -t pptx -o myfile.pptx myfile.md" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to work for a company that had all their presentations linked to excel sheets and it worked fine for some broad definition of fine.

If you have to keep Powerpoint as a presentation format, I'd advise to not use R for creating it. There are some packages that create great connections to Office products, but in my experience they break easily with development of packages and R versions. (one of the ones I played in the past, would recreate ggplot2 plots with actual shapes and lines on Powerpoint, resulting in a huge file)

With that in mind, I'd advise you to create the results programatically and dump it in an excel spread sheet and build the presentation linked to that spread sheet. To keep you sane, I'd do one file per month (if that is the kpi's periodicity). There are many nice packages that create excel spreadsheets, but I'd stick to csv files for their simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a look at SlideMight, a utility for merging data with PowerPoint templates; both text and images, in slides and tables. The usage is in principle similar to mail merge, with some more advanced stuff.

Possibly a solution for you would be to have the R program first write your data in a YAML, JSON or XML file; then it invokes the command-line version of SlideMight.

See [www.slidemight.com](http://www.slidemight.com).

Disclaimer: I am the developer and seller of SlideMight.